# Alerta This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur

Tags: android-studio

Tengo el siguiente codigo que funciona ok pero Studio me lo pinta como muestra la imagen, encontre varias respuestas pero sigo sin entender que tengo que hacer para que no salga mas pintado.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressBar progressBar;
static RingProgressBar ringProgressBar;
static int progress = 0;


Handler myHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage (Message msg){
        if(msg.what == 0){
            if(progress < 100){
                progress++;
                ringProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    ringProgressBar = (RingProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_1);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                    myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
 }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo Corregido y sin warning:**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


static RingProgressBar ringProgressBar;
static int progress = 0;

private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 0) {
            if (progress < 100) {
                progress++;
                ringProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        }
    }
}

private final MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    ringProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_1);
    final Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    ringProgressBar.setOnProgressListener(new RingProgressBar.OnProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void progressToComplete() {
            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Bienvenido!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Thread timer = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        sleep(2000);

                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
            timer.start();
        }
    });

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                    myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
   }
 }
```

Comment: podrias agregar que dice el warning?

Comment: Agregue la imagen del mensaje completo a la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando es que estas lekeando memoria. Esto pasa porque el handler instanciado de esa forma es una clase anonima que pertenece a la clase SplashActivity por lo tanto tiene una referencia al SplashActivity. Y a su vez el SplashActivity tiene una referencia al handler.

El Garbage Collector no podra eliminar al handler ni al splash porque ellos siempre se referenciaran unos a otros y de ahí el warning.

Para evitar el problema del leak de memoria deberas crear la clase del handler como un `private static class` y pasarle la referencia al Activity como un weak reference.

```
private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
   private final WeakReference<SplashActivity> mActivity;

   public MyHandler(SplashActivity activity) {
      mActivity = new WeakReference<SampleActivity>(activity);
   }

   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      SampleActivity activity = mActivity.get();
      if (activity != null) {
         // ...
      }
   }
}

private final MyHandler mHandler = new MyHandler(this);
```

Ahora el splash tiene una referencia del handler, pero la referencia del handler al splashActivity es weak y no la tendra en cuenta el Garbage Collector a la hora de eliminarlos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ahi corregi el codigo y no tengo mas el warning, lo deje en la pregunta agregado. Slds-.